# what are some unique ways monsters feed off people?

Tags: creature-design

So I'm creating a world that has several different species of monsters/creatures that feed off humans (as well as animals and other human-like creatures). Some are like classic monsters who will kill and tear apart the poor human to eat. But I don't want of the creatures to make a bloody mess of a person when they get hungry. So I've been trying to think of other ways creatures can feed off of humans.

For example:

- Dridders eat by immobilizing their prey, cocooning it, injecting venom/acid to liquify the prey, and then drinking them like a meat shake.
- Slimes will absorb prey.
- Spirits will syphon off of a person's life energy. This does not always kill the human.
- Demons will consume the person's soul.
- Vampires drink blood and don't have to kill.

This is all I could come up with at the moment, but I'd like to add more. Like, what if a creature could live off of a person's emotions or electrical energy? What if they fed on a person's dreams or senses? Magic does exist in this world so be as creative, or scientific, as you want. And the method of feeding doesn't have to kill the person.

Comment: Ex wives use court.......

Comment: This might be a little too open-ended of a question.

Comment: Scientifically speaking, only memes and depression can feed on your emotions.

Comment: @Mephistopheles no tag relating the Q with reality. Now, _really_, about that contract you were about to show to me...

Answer (score 3):

A gang of little monsters can [devour until clean the bones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQIo9r8ZcjM).

Meanwhile [giant ones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ec5QQ9486jo) can eat one human at once.

One parasite-like can absorb energy of everything of their victims eat, remotely.

A psychic one can drain brainwaves, maybe even manipulate them to remain forever in some condition, like a [sokushinbutsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokushinbutsu).

One insect-like use a human as nest to their eggs, like [wasps use spiders](https://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/mind-controlling-wasps-enslave-zombie-spiders-build-them-perfect-nest/)

Something like the [Venus flytrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_flytrap).

Answer (score 3):

I've always liked writing of mystical creatures which feed off of their prey's negative characteristics such as anger or age.  These creatures reverse the classic definition of monster by actually helping their victims while they feed.   The challenge is to find the catastrophic result hidden within the apparently beneficial affect.

- A being which eats anger might leave its victims passionless; trapped by apathetic inertia and tolerant to a point of self abuse.
- A being which eats age might take experience with it.  So the aging scientist who might actually be able to cure the plague becomes an energetic child but looses the critically needed scientific training and wisdom.

Another cool aspect of monsters which benefit their victims is the possibility that killing the monster might undo the good that they have done.  That former scientist who is enjoying his new youth might not care enough about the plague victims to give it up.  Motivating heroes to fall makes for good turmoil both inside the hero's mind and among the people who depend on them.